# Import MP3 in iOS app (using code)

Tags: ios, media

Is it possible to import a *.mp3 file from my app resources folder into iTunes?

My app contains a soundtrack, and I want to export it to the users' media library so he/she can listen it using their normal media player.

I couldn't find anything in the iOS docs (at least, not where I looked)

Comment: Consider putting the song on iTunes store and provide a link to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is technically possible, in fact @[H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3) has done so [here](https://github.com/H2CO3/MFMusicLibrary).

However, this is a solution requires a jailbroken device and usage of private API. If you're looking to get your an app that does this in the App Store, I'm sorry to say it, but you're out of luck. This is not possible.